# Executing same php script consecutively

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to execute a script named `csearch.php` five times with the interval of 60 secs. I tried `shell_exec` and `exec` but it says, it can't fork, etc. I think the best way (since this is on a shared host) is by using `include()`.

```
include('csearch.php');
sleep(60);
include('csearch.php');
sleep(60);
include('csearch.php');
sleep(60);
include('csearch.php');
sleep(60);
include('csearch.php');
```

`csearch.php` contains functions, etc. I'm wondering if this is possible (the above code). If not, what's the best way you can recommend? Thanks.

Edit, this is how I do it with `exec` and fails:

```
exec('/path/to/php /path/to/csearch.php');
```

Comment: How are you doing your `exec()`? This is how you should do it and it should work. Plus, you can't `include()` the same script...

Comment: what about exec('/usr/bin/php /path/to/php /path/to/csearch.php'); ?

Comment: @Shikiryu - you can include the same script. That's why PHP also provides `include_once()` for cases where you don't want to.

Comment: @Shikiryu: you can include a file as many times as you want, but if it's got function defnitions in there, you'll get a fatal error from trying to redeclare the same function.

Comment: @Marc B : that was my point. The OP clearly said **csearch.php contains functions, etc.**. What I meant with *can't include the same script*... Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take an approach similar to Berry's suggestion, but without the use of curl.

Wrap the code in csearch.php in a function (e.g. perform_action).

```
require_once('csearch.php');

for ($i = 0, $n = 5; $i < $n; $i++) {
    perform_action();

    if ($i < $n - 1) {
        // Only sleep if you need to
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do this? Sounds to me that you might have a need for a cronjob, or otherwise made a mistake in your script. Anyway, if the script is reachable from the "outside" (e.g. executable over HTTP), you might want to use cURL, as that can do the thing you request.

```
include('csearch.php');

$res = curl_init( 'http://site.com/csearch.php' );

while( $i < 5 ) {
   curl_exec( $res );
   sleep( 60 );
   $i ++;
}
```

But seriously, the chance that you actually need to do this is *very* slim.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

- Zend Queue: http://www.zend.com/en/products/platform/product-comparison/job-queues
- GearMan: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php